# Canvas rectangles are having the same x and y but shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rect

Hey so I'm making an HTML5 game and I want to have buttons made on canvas.

```
     Button = function(text, x, y, width, height){
            self.x = x;
            self.y = y;
            self.width = width;
            self.height = height;

            self.createButton = function(){
                ctx.save();
                ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                ctx.fillRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height);

                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.font = '30px Arial';
                ctx.fillText(self.text, self.x, self.y + (self.height / 2));

                ctx.restore();
            }

        self.createButton();

        return self;
    }
```

That's my function to make a button, somewhere else in my code I make two buttons -

```
       var button1 = Button('Button 1', WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 200, 40);

        var button2 = Button('Button 2', WIDTH / 2, (HEIGHT / 2) + 50, 200, 40);

        console.log('button1 x: ', button1.x);
        console.log('button1 y: ', button1.y);


        console.log('button2 x: ', button2.x);
        console.log('button2 y: ', button2.y);
```

The buttons wind up being drawn separately.. but when I console out the x and ys in the code they're both exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The buttons wind up being drawn separately.. but when I console out the x and ys in the code they're both exactly the same.

That is because you are assigning the values to the *global* variable `self`, [which already exists, and refers to the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/self).

So you are not working with separate variables here as you thought, but with one and the same – overwriting its x, y, … properties each time.

Insert this as the first line into your function, to create a *local* variable and initialize it as an empty object:

```
var self = {};
```

Without initializing it as an (empty) object, you would get an error message saying something like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined`. Only reason you did not get this with your code, is because `self` was an existing object before already.

But to avoid confusion, it might be better to choose a different variable name to begin with – using `_self` instead is pretty common to store the reference to itself inside an object.